# iOS - Passing blocks to functions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I have a method call (it's a call from AFNetworking):

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]);

                                     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                     }];
```

and I'm trying to pull the sucess and failure blocks out into a separate variable, that I can later pass into the method. But I can't figure out how to declare the blocks as variables. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
IDontKnowWhatKindOfDataTypeGoesHere successBlock = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
  NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]);  
}
```

and the same for the failureBlock.

So then I'm looking to make the `AFJSONRequestOperation` call like:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
```

But I cant figure how what the data types of the successBlock and failureBlock should be.

This is more for organization I suppose. I have a lot of code in my successBlock and the autoformatting of Xcode pushes is all to the right side of the screen which is totally annoying. So if I can pull it out (which should be possible, right), then I can organize my code better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's awkward until you get used to it.  The variable name appears mixed in with the type...

```
void (^success)(NSURLRequest *, NSHTTPURLResponse *, id) = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
   NSLog(@"request is %@, response is %@ and json is %@", request, response, JSON);
};
```

The stack variable name in this case is success.  You can now refer to it in subsequent expressions that take the same type, like ...

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperationJSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                        success:success];
```

You can also make a block an property, like this:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^success)(NSURLRequest *, NSHTTPURLResponse *, id);
```

And call it like this:

```
self.success(aRequest, aResponse, someJSON);
```

Remember to nil it out when you're done calling it, so the caller has less to worry about creating a retain cycle.

**Edit**: good suggestion in commentary about using typedef to make this easier on the eyes and fingers:

```
typedef void (^SuccesBlock)(NSURLRequest *, NSHTTPURLResponse *, id);
```

So the stack variable looks like this:

```
SuccessBlock success = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
   NSLog(@"request is %@, response is %@ and json is %@", request, response, JSON);
};
```

and the property looks like this:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) SuccessBlock success;
```

Comment: This is a really clear answer. Thanks so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: Creating a typedef for the block type can also streamline the code, especially if you want to use the block type in your own method declarations.