# Objective-C Return a String in NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to create a NSString function to return a string that has the NSURLSessionDataTask

```
- (NSString *) retrieveData
{
    self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    self.dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        if(data)
        {
            self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.json);

            for(NSDictionary *stateArray in self.json)
            {
                NSString *sName = stateArray[@"State"];
                if(self.state == sName)
                {
                    NSString *sFlag = stateArray[@"State_Flag_Path"];
                    return sFlag;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to fetch URL: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    [self.dataTask resume];
}
```

Then, I get an error message for incompatible block pointer types issue.
Can anyone please help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871506/how-to-get-data-to-return-from-nsurlsessiondatatask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way...
return the string after

```
[self.dataTask resume];
```